# Random core dumps

Tags: c, linux, gcc, struct, message-queue

I'm writing a project, in which there are two programs, client and server, client sends a string to server, server process it and then sends it back to the client(there can be multiple clients at the same time, and this is where lies my problem). I'm sending process ID from client in the same string that needs to be processed, server extracts process ID. However I'm getting random Core dumps, which arent consistant. Most of the time it works fine. It happens right before invoking `strtol()` call in `receive_message(...)` function.

Server `receive_message(...)` function:

```
int receive_message(struct message *x){
    int ret_val, z;
    ret_val = msgrcv(msg_q_id, x, MAX, 0, 0);
    if (ret_val == -1){
        if (signal_detection == 1){
            exit(0);
        }
    perror("COULDNT receive a message!");
        exit(-1);
    } else {
    int c = 0;
        while (x->mtext[c] != '!'){
            ++c;
        }
    int h = c;
        char tab[strlen(x -> mtext) - c];
        int s = 0;
        for (int counter = c + 1; counter < strlen(x->mtext); ++counter){
            tab[s++] = x->mtext[counter];
        }
    printf("\n%s\n", tab);
        z = strtol(tab, NULL, 10);
        memset((x -> mtext) + h, 0, strlen(x -> mtext) - 1 - c);
        printf("message received: %s\n", x -> mtext);
    }
    return z;
}
```

Whole server code:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define MAX 255
#define CLIENT 1
#define SERVER 2

int signal_detection = 0;
int msg_q_id;
key_t msg_q_key;
struct message;

void create_queue();
void send_message(struct message *x, int pid);
int receive_message(struct message *x);
void delete_message_q();
void to_upper_case(struct message *x);
void signal_handler(int signum, siginfo_t *info, void *ptr);

struct message{
    long int mtype;
    char mtext[MAX];
};

int main(){
    struct message member_of_message;
    struct message *ptr;
    struct sigaction sig;
    int sig_ret;
    ptr = &member_of_message;
    sig.sa_sigaction = signal_handler;
    sig_ret = sigaction(SIGINT, &sig, NULL);
    if (sig_ret == -1){
        perror("sigaction fail");
    }
    create_queue();
    while (1){
    int pid;
        memset(member_of_message.mtext, 0, strlen(member_of_message.mtext));
        printf("waiting for message\n");
        pid = receive_message(ptr);
        to_upper_case(ptr);
        printf("After uppering: %s\n", member_of_message.mtext);
        send_message(ptr, pid);
        sleep(1);
    }
}

void create_queue(){
    printf("starting to create queue\n");
    msg_q_key = ftok(",", 4);
    msg_q_id = msgget(msg_q_key, 0700|IPC_CREAT);
    if (msg_q_id == -1){
        perror("COULDNT create msgq");
        exit(-1);
    } else {
    printf("succesfully created: %d !\n", msg_q_id);
    }
}

void send_message(struct message *x, int pid){
    int ret_val;
    x -> mtype = pid + 1;
    wysylanie:
    ret_val = msgsnd(msg_q_id, x, strlen(x -> mtext) + 1, 0);
    if (ret_val == -1){
        if (errno == EAGAIN){
                perror("message queue is full!");
                goto wysylanie;
        }
    perror("COULDNT send a message");
        exit(-1);
    } else {
    printf("message sent!\n");
    }
}

int receive_message(struct message *x){
    int ret_val, z;
    ret_val = msgrcv(msg_q_id, x, MAX, 0, 0);
    if (ret_val == -1){
        if (signal_detection == 1){
            exit(0);
        }
    perror("COULDNT receive a message!");
        exit(-1);
    } else {
    int c = 0;
        while (x->mtext[c] != '!'){
            ++c;
        }
    int h = c;
        char tab[strlen(x -> mtext) - c];
        int s = 0;
        for (int counter = c + 1; counter < strlen(x->mtext) - 1; ++counter){
            tab[s++] = x->mtext[counter];
        }
    printf("\n%s\n", tab);
        z = strtol(tab, NULL, 10);
        memset((x -> mtext) + h, 0, strlen(x -> mtext) - 1 - c);
        printf("message received: %s\n", x -> mtext);
    }
    return z;
}

void delete_message_q(){
    int ret_val;
    ret_val = msgctl(msg_q_id, IPC_RMID, 0);
    if (ret_val == -1){
        perror("COULDNT remove message queue");
        exit(-1);
    } else {
    printf("message queue deleted!\n");
    }
}

void to_upper_case(struct message *x){
    for (int counter = 0; counter < strlen(x->mtext); ++counter){
        x->mtext[counter] = toupper(x->mtext[counter]);
    }
}

void signal_handler(int signum, siginfo_t *info, void *ptr){
    signal_detection = 1;
    printf("\nReceived a signal!\nstopping iteration\n");
    delete_message_q();
}
```

Client code:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 255
#define CLIENT 1
#define SERVER 2
#define M_SENT 3

int msg_q_id;
key_t msg_q_key;
struct message;
int pid;
void create_queue();
void *send_message();
void *receive_message(void *arg);

struct message{
    long int mtype;
    char mtext[MAX];
};

int main(){
    struct message member_of_message;
    struct message *ptr;
    int thread_val;
    ptr = &member_of_message;
    pthread_t pid1, pid2;
    create_queue();
    sleep(1);
    printf("creating thread1......\n");
    thread_val = pthread_create(&pid1, NULL, send_message, NULL);
    if (thread_val != 0){
        perror("couldnt create thread");
        exit(-1);
    }
    printf("creating thread2......\n");
    thread_val = pthread_create(&pid2, NULL, receive_message, ptr);
    if (thread_val != 0){
        perror("couldnt create thread");
        exit(-1);
    }
    thread_val = pthread_join(pid1, NULL);
    if (thread_val != 0){
        perror("couldnt create thread");
        exit(-1);
    }
    thread_val = pthread_join(pid2, NULL);
    if (thread_val != 0){
        perror("couldnt create thread");
        exit(-1);
    }
}

void create_queue(){
    printf("starting creation of a queue\n");
    msg_q_key = ftok(",", 4);
    msg_q_id = msgget(msg_q_key, 0700|IPC_CREAT);
    if (msg_q_id == -1){
        perror("COULDNT create msgq");
        exit(-1);
    } else {
    printf("succesfully created: %d !\n", msg_q_id);
    }
}

void *send_message(){
    int last_val;
    struct message member_of_message;
    int ret_val;
    char rub[10000];
    for (int message_counter = 0; message_counter < M_SENT; ++message_counter){
        pid = getpid();
        member_of_message.mtype = pid;
        char arr[MAX];
        if (fgets(arr, MAX - 20, stdin) == NULL){
            perror("not a single char read, message sent is empty");
        }
    if (strlen(arr) == 1){
            perror("cannot send empty message!");
            exit(-1);
        }
    if (strchr(arr, '\n') == NULL){
            perror("Przepelniono komunikat!");
            fgets(rub, 10000, stdin);
        }
    char temp_arr[20];
        int sp_retval;
        sp_retval = sprintf(temp_arr, "%d", pid);
        if (sp_retval == 0){
            perror("0 bytes read");
            exit(-1);
        }
    for (int counter = 0; counter < strlen(arr) - 1; ++counter){
            member_of_message.mtext[counter] = arr[counter];
            last_val = counter;
        }
member_of_message.mtext[last_val + 1] = '!';
        strcat(member_of_message.mtext, temp_arr);
        wysylanie:
        ret_val = msgsnd(msg_q_id, (struct message*)&member_of_message, strlen(member_of_message.mtext), 0);
        if (ret_val == -1){
            if (errno == EAGAIN){
                perror("message queue is full!");
                goto wysylanie;
            }
            perror("COULDNT send a message");
            exit(-1);
        } else {
        printf("message sent!, PID: %d \n", pid);
        memset(member_of_message.mtext, 0, strlen(member_of_message.mtext));
        }
    }
}

void *receive_message(void *arg){
    int ret_val;
    for (int message_counter = 0; message_counter < M_SENT; ++message_counter){
        sleep(1);
        ((struct message*)arg)->mtype = pid + 1;
        ret_val = msgrcv(msg_q_id, (struct message*)arg, MAX, ((struct message*)arg)->mtype, 0);
        if (ret_val == -1){
            perror("COULDNT receive a message!");
            exit(-1);
        } else {
        printf("message received: %s\n", ((struct message*)arg)->mtext);
        memset(((struct message*)arg)->mtext, 0, strlen(((struct message*)arg)->mtext));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it missing `tab[s] = '\0'`?

Comment: @KamilCuk tried that, core dumps still exist;/

Comment: This line: `ret_val = msgsnd(msg_q_id, (struct message*)&member_of_message, strlen(member_of_$` does not compile. Please use line-wrapping when cut/pasting the code.

Comment: @EmployedRussian right, I edited it, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Anyway, compile with `-Wall -Wextra -fsanitize=undefined,address -g3` and wait for errors. It will most probably catch most problems.

Comment: Also, your first port of call for this class of problem -- before asking questions here -- should be to run your program under Valgrind.

Answer (score 2):

```
ret_val = msgsnd(msg_q_id, (struct message*)&member_of_message, strlen(member_of_message.mtext), 0);
```

This line shows most clearly the problem with this code. You are sending *messages* that consist of a message type and message text. The size of a *message* cannot possibly equal the length of the message text because there also needs to be some number of bytes sent to hold the message type.